# Ajax success not running after url php completed

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a function to check email, first and last name.

```
function checkcontactdetails(){
var details = {
  'email'       : jQuery('#email').val(),
  'first_name'  : jQuery('#first_name').val(),
  'last_name'   : jQuery('#last_name').val(),
 };
 jQuery.ajax({
   url          :   'checkcontactdetails.php',
   type         :   'POST',
   data         :   details,
   success      :   function(data){
      if(data != 'passed'){
         jQuery('#payment-errors-step2').html(data);
      }
      if(data == 'passed'){
          $('.step3').show();
          $('#payment-errors-step2').html("");
      }
   },
   error : function(){alert("Something Went Wrong");},
 });
}
```

the function is called here:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" id="checkoutbtn1" onclick="checkcontactdetails();">Next Step1</button>
```

the errors go here:

```
<span class="bg-danger" id="payment-errors-step2"></span>
```

this is my checkcontactdetails.php page being called:

```
<?php
  include 'core/initial.php';

  $email      = sanitize($_POST['email']);
  $first_name = sanitize($_POST['first_name']);
  $last_name  = sanitize($_POST['last_name']);

  $errors = array();
  $required = array(
    'email'     => 'Email',
    'first_name'=> 'First Name',
    'last_name' => 'Last Name',
  );

  //Check if all required fields are filled out
  foreach($required as $f => $d){
    if(empty($_POST[$f])  || $_POST[$f] ==  ''){
      $errors[] = $d.'  is required.';
    }
  }

  //Check if valid email address
  if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid email.';
  }

  if(!empty($errors)){
    echo display_errors($errors);
  }else {
    echo 'passed';
  }

 ?>
```

What i have done so far is tested the execution of the button, and get an alert stating "passed"
So i know the ajax call gets to the success step because a) i get "passed" and b) the errors get removed by this code:

```
if(data != 'passed'){
   jQuery('#payment-errors-step2').html(data);
 }
```

What i want to do is once the success is "passed" to show the next step of the process, in this case is step 3, and to clear errors if present.

I have been going around and around with this, i think i have the syntax correct, so i have other functions similarly setup (which work), but for some reason this one doesn't.

To note, i have set each step to display: none, so the only way to display the steps is to do it via the functions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using $('#checkoutbtn1').on('click',function(){ }?. No need to this line.

Comment: I have just removed the button,